# Android - how to get location of friend

Tags: android, gps, location, google-latitude

Is there a way I can access the data in Google Latitude to return the location of a fellow Latitude user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there's no specific Android API as yet, however you can access latitude through an [HTTP API](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/overview.html) if you're willing to hand code the HTTP requests yourself.